# Identifier "function_name" is undefined when calling a function

Tags: c++

I have declared a function `bool Network::areFriends(User & usr1, User & usr2)`  which when called unfortunately I am met with

```
identifier "function_name" is undefined
```

And the classes in which I am referring to.

Wall.h

```cpp
#pragma once
class Wall
{
private:
    std::list<Message> msgs_posted;
    User* w_owner;
public:
    Wall() = delete;
    Wall(User* wownr);
    virtual ~Wall();

    void postMsg(User& usr ,Message msg);

    void toString();

    std::list<Message> getMsgsPosted();

};
```

Wall.cpp

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

Wall::Wall(User * wownr)
    :w_owner(wownr)
{
}

Wall::~Wall()
{
}

void Wall::postMsg(User& usr, Message msg)
{
    //if are friends 
    if ((usr == *this->w_owner) || areFriends(usr,*this->w_owner)){
        msgs_posted.push_back(msg);
        /* does it get copied altogether? */
    }
    else 
        std::cout << "You can not post at this person's wall." << std::endl;
}

void Wall::toString()
{
    std::list<Message> ::iterator tmp_it;
    for (tmp_it = msgs_posted.begin(); tmp_it!= msgs_posted.end(); tmp_it++) {
        tmp_it->toString();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

std::list<Message> Wall::getMsgsPosted()
{
    return msgs_posted;
}
```

Network.h

```cpp
#pragma once
class Network
{
private:
    /* Singleton Implementation */
    static Network* instance;
    Network();

    /* Misc */
    std::list<User> users;
    std::list<User>::iterator usr_it;
    std::map<User, std::list<User*> > connections; // maybe pointer to users list? 
    std::map<User, std::list<User*> >::iterator map_it;

public:
    /* Singleton Implementation */
    Network(const Network&) = delete;
    Network& operator=(const Network&) = delete;
    ~Network();
    static Network& getInstance();

    /* Other methods */
    bool u_Exists(User& usr);
    void addUser();
    void addUser(User& usr);
    void deleteUser(User& usr);
    void connectUsers(User& usr1, User& usr2);

    std::list<User> hasFriends(User& usr);
    bool areFriends(User& usr1, User& usr2);
    std::list<User> commonFriends(User* usr1, User* usr2);

};
```

Network.cpp

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
Network::Network()
{}

...

Network& Network::getInstance()
{
    static Network instance;
    return instance;
}

bool Network::areFriends(User & usr1, User & usr2)
{
    if (usr1 == usr2) {
        return false;
    }
    else /*to be added*/{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function that I am referring to is  `bool Network::areFriends(User & usr1, User & usr2)` , used in

```
void Wall::postMsg(User& usr, Message msg)
{
    //if are friends 
    if ((usr == *this->w_owner) || areFriends(usr,*this->w_owner)){
```

If needed I will post the rest of the classes but didn't due to size.

Comment: What's the exact error message you're getting, and what code line is it on?

Comment: Your explanation is a little garbled and I'm having trouble following. Could you at least indicate which line in the code above produces the error?

Comment: Nothing in what you've posted above says to me that this is a circular dependency problem, or a precompiled header problem. Just looks like a regular compiler error to me. But more information is needed.

Comment: I think this is because you're trying to call `areFriends` (a member of `Network`) from `Wall::postMsg`.  You need a `Network` object to call `areFriends` on.

Comment: I'm sorry the error I'm currently getting is an unknown identifier for the function areFriends from class Network.

Comment: but problem is that if I change the order in the pch.h file the whole project "crumbles" and especially when I try to put Network.h first.

Comment: If headers file can't be put in any order then that's a problem. But your problem is something else. You're trying to call a `Network` function without an instance of a `Network` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So shouldn't it be something like this

```
if ((usr == *this->w_owner) || Network::getInstance().areFriends(usr,*this->w_owner)){
```

In the code you've posted there's no instance of `Network` to call the `areFriends` function on.

Comment: That seems to cover the basis of the problem indeed, all that's left is some minor troubleshooting afterwards and the fact that the order of the headers can't be changed.

Comment: on further notice that seems to be also throwing an unhandled a read access violation.
_Right_data was 0x20 , on that check.